# How does a database handle error during commitment process or rollback process?

Tags: database, transactions

Given the simple Transaction flow: `Start` -> `make changes` -> `commit` (`error` -> `rollback`).

1. I assume that during `commit`, changes are already made to the hard disk where the database is stored.
   Then how would a database handle error that happens midway during `commit`?
2. Assuming and error as in #1 leads to a `rollback`, how would a database handle error that occurs during this `rollback`?

Is there a fail-safe, data-corruption-free mechanism to handle all this, or do we just hope for the best?

Comment: "Is there a fail-safe, data-corruption-free mechanism to handle all this?" -- Any decent database engine saves the data to separate file/blocks (e.g. the redo log) as "uncommitted", and not in directly in the table. Once the transaction is committed this separate are is marked as "committed" **with a single disk change**. At this point the data is considered committed. It will be applied to the main table in a deffered way later (milliseconds later) by a separate process. If there's a crash, the engine will find the redo log and will apply all committed transactions, upon restart.

Comment: "...or do we just hope for the best?" -- High end and middle tier engines use replication for the data being committed. For example, Aurora replicates to 5 other boxes (for a total of 6 servers). Should any of them crash there are still 5 others with the data. Simpler databases don't have replication, or may have just one mirror. But in the end, everything can fail, so you are right we always prepare for the worst and hope for the best.